# この回答はどのあたりがスパムでしょうか？改善の余地はありませんか？

Tags: 討議

プログラミングに関する情報サイトを運営されている方から、そのサイトの記事を元に、おすすめチュートリアルについて回答が投稿されました。

- [Unity初心者が取り組むべきチュートリアルを教えてください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/31838/8000)

この回答についてスパム通報があり、マイナス投票もされているようです。

当サイトでは[宣伝目的の投稿や、関係者であることを隠して製品・サービスなどの紹介をすることを禁止しています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)が、それはとりあえず置いといて、投稿の内容について考えます。

挙げられているチュートリアルはそこまで的外れでもなさそうですし、内容に関する説明が書かれている点はよい回答だとも思います。

また自サイトからの転載自体を禁止しているわけでもありません。権利問題がクリアできて、このサイトに合った内容・形式であればよいでしょう。リンクのみの回答になっても困ります。

つまり、書きようによっては問題のない投稿になりえたのではと思ったのです。

この回答のスパムたる要素、あるいは質の低いところはどこだと思いますか？それは改善することが可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 6):

私は、質問の形に問題があったのだと思いましたので、質問の方にクローズ票を入れましたが、件の回答者さんの回答の作り方はそれはそれで、スパムと見なされても仕方ないと思います。
質問や既存の回答と整合していません。

- 「ウェブページをダウンロードしてきてhtmlのソースが端末画面に表示されるような入門的なプログラム」の質問に対して、[gcc やサーバ構築に関する書籍のリストを回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/31841/3054)。
  コード例も含め質問に答えている既存の回答がある中で、これを付け加える意義はありません。
- 「Rユーザのための比較対象表など」を求める質問に対して、[一般的な Python 入門書のみのリストを回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/31839/3054)。
  きちんと R やデータ分析に触れた既存の回答が複数ある中で、これを付け加える意義はありません。
- 「ジャンルに分類して教えて頂けませんか？」という質問に対して、[分類のないリストを回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/31838/3054)。
  リストの半分（「初めてのUnity」「Unity本家」「世界よ、これが本当の Unity 講座だ」）が既存の回答（wiki）と重複しています。
  重複している部分に関しても、内容の説明がある点は wiki を改善していると思いますが、ただ重複させたままというのは配慮に欠けると思います。
  Web 上のリソースであるにも関わらず、URL（リンク）も示されていません。

とは言え、最後のケース（今回議題になっている物）などは結果として結構「当っている」回答になっていると思いますし、目くじらを立てるほどの物ではなく、別の場所であれば歓迎されたかも知れませんね。

スパムか否かは、こういった微妙なケースでは無理に判定する必要はないと思います。
Stack Overflow で求められる回答の形と違っているならマイナス票が入りますので、それで十分かと。

Answer (score 5):

### スパムとは何か

[What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/301070)

が一つの基準になると思います。「聞かれてもないのに投稿される広告的な内容」である場合(のみ)に、スパム通報はされるべきではないでしょうか。

### 今回のケースはスパムか

自己質問して自己回答を繰り返すなどしていたら、さすがにスパムでしょうが、特にそういうわけでもなさそうですし、また、聞かれたことに対してきちんと回答しているように見受けられます。私はスパムではないと思います。

### downvote は適切か

今回の回答は、一旦投稿者のサイトに飛ばないとそれぞれのチュートリアルに行けないようになっている様子です。その意味でこの回答は広告的です。downvote の理由は主にそれだと思います。

…広告的なものに対して、画一的にdownvote すべきかしないべきかを決めるのはむずかしいと考えます。広告的であっても素晴らしい回答は書きうると思いますし、しかし一方で広告的な内容ばかりが投稿されるスタックオーバーフローがプログラマにとって価値のあるサイトになっているイメージはちょっとわきません。

各コミュニティメンバーが、価値のある投稿だと思えば upvote, サイトの価値をむしろ毀損すると思えば downvote すれば良いのではないでしょうか。