# What is the filmの投稿について

Tags: 討議

[What is the film](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41124/what-is-the-film)

> "youtubeへのリンク"
>   この映画のタイトルを教えて下さい
>   女優の名前もお願いします

という投稿がSPAMであり削除されるべきと思い報告したのですが却下されました。どう見てもプログラミングと無関係だと思うのですが却下理由が知りたいです。
またYuki Inoueさんはオフトピックとして日本語化されるか英語版Stack Overflowが適切と投票されていますが、どのように改善されれば再オープンされるのか判断基準を聞かせていただきたいです。（revision 1では英語での質問でした。）

---

広義にはオフトピックかもしれませんが、SOにおけるオフトピックは同時に改善待ちでもあります。この投稿は改善を見込めるような内容なのでしょうか？
なお、

- [SO meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2643/%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)
- [Yahoo知恵袋](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11184958701)
- [教えてGoo](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/10225364.html)

などにも投稿されていますが、これらを見るまでもなくSPAMと判断できないものなのでしょうか？

Comment: 詳細は私からは見えませんが、当該質問は既に削除されたようです。

Comment: 質問はクローズされてから数日の間「改善待ち (on hold)」になりますが、だからといって「クローズされた質問は必ず改善できる」とは言っていないのではないでしょうか？　そもそも「改善待ち」の機能自体は[一度「クローズ」と言われてしまうと再編集しにくいという問題から導入された](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497/341401)ものなので、その点から考えてもクローズの判断に「改善を見込めるかどうか」を加える必要は無いと思いました。

Comment: 「どう見てもプログラミングに関係ない質問」と「スパムである質問」には差があるな、とも思います。（どちらも最終的には削除されるべきだ、という部分は同じですね。）

Comment: @nekketsuuu 下の回答で、nekketsuuu さんの記述に言及しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はい。却下ボタンを押してしまったのは自分です。これは操作ミスです。すいません。。

。もう少し今回何が起きたのかを説明しますと、まず、最初に英語の投稿があったので、ひとまずクローズ投票しました。それが現在の、「英語版に投稿するか日本語に直してくれ」、のクローズ投票です。

コメントなしでクローズされた投稿に対して、自動で通報が発生します。これはその他通報と同じ扱いになります。普段英語質問をクローズする際にもれなく発生して、その度に却下していていたのですが、今回もそれと同じように却下したところ、それより前に通報してくださっていた spam フラグまで却下され、今に至っています。

ひとまず、今のクローズ表示は正しくないですね…編集など行います。

---

## spam, close, 改善待ちについて

nekketsuu さんも仰ってくれていますが、「クローズされた == 改善の見込みがある」わけではない、という認識です。「クローズする == これ以上コミュニティとして回答を求めない」という認識です。そして、 on hold が改善待ちになっているのが、ややこしさの一員かなとも思いました。「保留中」が, on hold に一番対応する日本語かなとは思ったりします。

何をもって spam とするのかどうかは、おそらくコミュニティが決めることだと思っています。というのも、[それについて述べている meta のページ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/301070)を見ましたが、「厳しめに寄せた基準はこう」「ただし、コミュニティごとに違っていたりするし、より緩和しているポリシーを採用していたりする。 Stackoverflow 本家も含む。」となっていたりするので。。

spam をとても厳密に運用した場合のマイナスは何かをちょっと考えていました。たとえば、まったく新規のユーザーが、普通に yahoo 知恵袋などに投稿するのと同じように、スタックオーバーフローに投稿したところ、何だかスパム判定をくらってしまった、とかがあると、それは何か厳しすぎるかもしれない、と個人的には思ったりします。クローズは妥当ですが、スパムはどうなのだろう、という観点です。

そういった部分を含めて、コミュニティが決めるにあたって、さしあたって利用できる基準としては、例えば[自分が以前投稿したこれ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2403/754)とかだと思っています。ただ、程度問題の部分もあるので、メンバーが実際にスパム投票(通報)をして運用していくなかで、加減が明確になってくればいいかな、と思っています。

Comment: また、英語オフトピック投票は、「日本語化されるか英語版Stack Overflowが適切」である場合のみに行われるべきである、という話が今回あるかなと思っています。…たしかに、これはその通りだと考えられ、デフォルトの表示文では不適切な場合(今回のような)には、手動でコメントなどを残しておくべきでした。今後は注意いたします。。

Comment: Youtube再生を目的としたSPAM・広告ではないとの見解でしょうか？

Comment: あ、なるほど、再生数をかせぐためにリンクを貼っている、と考えられるのですね。 (自分の中で、 SPAM == Car Insurance Buy Now など、のような連想がなりたっていて、 SPAM と認識していなかった)

Comment: そして, spam とは何かということで
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/301070 を読み直している。。

Comment: 結局Yuki Inoueさんの判断としてはspamではなく、改善の見込みがある投稿ということでしょうか？ 「どのように改善されれば再オープンされるのか判断基準を聞かせていただきたい」にお答えください。

Comment: @sayuri 追記いたしました。

Comment: 件の質問はメタ含め他サイトにもマルチポストこそしていましたが、1回だけでスパムかどうかを判断するのは難しいと思います(場違いであれど、私自身は純粋な回答を求める質問だと感じました)。ただしSO的にオフトピックな質問だったのは間違いないと思います。